# Choosing two points from $[0,1]$ probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We are choosing two random points among section $[0,1]$. These create 3 sections. The sections lengths are different and called $x,y,z$. Show the sample space using $x,y$.

My solution:

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
\Omega\ =\ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z\ |\ x+y+z\ =\ 1\}\\
=\ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z\ |\ z\ =\ 1-x-y\}\\
=\ \{< x,\ y,1-x-y> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< 1-x-y\}\\
=\ \{< x,\ y,\ 1-x-y> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< 1-x-y\}
\end{array}$

I don't know if it's right. They are now asking me to draw this graphically and I have no idea how to, which makes me think is might be wrong.

Comment: Why do you say $x+y+z=1$? They could be $x=\dfrac{1}{8},y=\dfrac{1}{4},z=\dfrac{1}{2}$, for example.

Comment: Well if you take a section of the length of 1 (aka from 0 to 1). You throw there some random 2 points, and this creates 3 sections, the lengths of the sections add up to 1, I don't see how not

Comment: Ah, okay. I misread and thought $x,y,z$ were the points. You should say they are sections' *lengths* though.

Comment: Edited. Is there any way you could help?

Comment: I think you are over complicating things. $x$ can have any length from $0$ to $1$. Then $y$ can have any length from $0$ to $1-x$. From there, $z$ is determined so you don't need to worry about it in the sample space. Does that help?

Comment: @roundsquare Yeah but how do you address the fact they all have to be different?

Comment: @ucei fair enough - my bad. Ignoring that restriction, the sample space is a triangle on the $x,y$ plane. Then, you need to exclude the situations where, given $x$, either $x=y$, $x=z$, or $y=z$. For the first case, that is the line $y=x$. For the second case, that is $y=(1-x)/2$. For the third case, that is $y=1-2x$. These three lines, where they intersect the original triangle, are all excluded. If you are drawing it, I would probably put these lines in red or something and point out that they are excluded from the sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to post this as an answer so I can include a picture. I think its easier to start with the picture and then try to write out the sample space algebraically.

$z$ is totally determined by $x$ and $y$ so we can just focus on $x$ and $y$.

First, ignore equality conditions. The sample space is then the green area below:
[image]

Now, we need to remove the parts of this where any of $x$, $y$, and $z$ are equal. Each of these are lines in the plane. To find these, we use the fact that $x + y + z = 1$. For:

(1) $x=y$ the line is $y=x$

(2) $x=z$ it is $x + y + x = 1$ so $y = 1 - 2x$

(3) $y = z$ it is $x + y + y = 1$ so $y = (1 - x)/2$

We can draw these lines in red to show what is excluded:
[image]

If you want to write it out algebraically, you can do that like this:

$\Omega=\{<x, y>|x+1=1,x>0, y>0\}-\{<x, y>|y=x\}-\{<x, y>|y=1-2x\}-\{<x, y>|y=(1-x)/2\}$

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the sample space $\Omega$ of possibles triplets $(x,y,z)$ formed by the different lengths of the sections, you're almost right.

First of all, let's clarify that if you're considering ordering $x,y,z$ then it is because you're taking $x$ as the length of the shortest section, $z$ as the length of the largest section, and $y$ as the length of the left one. If you wanted to consider $x,y,z$ as the lengths of the first, second and third section respectively, then they wouldn't have to be ordered at all.

Having said that, your sample space seems almost ok. You can't get rid of the $z=1-x-y$ so easily, since there was hidden the condition $z\le1$, that we need to say $y\le1$. You can correct this simly writing $\Omega=\{(x,y,1-x-y)\mid0\le x<y<1-x-y\le1\}$.

I'd like to make a note: As were pointed out in the comments and you wrote yourself, $z$ is completely determined by $x$ and $y$ (in fact any of them is determined by the other two), so you don't need it as part of your triplet. It's not wrong, it's just superfluous, so you could do a sample space considering the possible pairs $(x,y)$ instead (with the same conditions $0\le x<y<1-x-y\le1$), and get rid of the extra information. It depends on what you want to construct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I actually forgot to mention the lengths of the sections are different! I edited it now. Does it change your answer? Also in regard to the first part of your answer (which I haven't quite understood).

Comment: It's true that z is determined by x and y. But how do you address the fact that x and y need to be different than z? If I simply say something like 0<=x<y, and then z leave it to it, then how do I make sure x and y are different from z?

Comment: I added the extra inequality. On the other hand, what I mean at the first part is that you're choosing $x$ to be less than $y$ and $z$, so this means that you're choosing $x$ to represent the shortest length you get. Similarly you're choosing $z$ to represent the largest length you get, hence $y$ represents the left one. There's no problem with that; I just wanted to make sure you knew it. It would be different if you wanted to consider $x$ as then length of the first section you get and the same for $y$ and $z$